# how do i get facebook user login status?

Tags: php, facebook, yii

I am using yii framework and want to know the login status of facebook user.
I am using $_REQUEST["code"] to get the user login status, but am facing some problem. I want to know if I can check session for it or get logged in status some other way..??

Comment: Please add more details. What is the "some problem" are are facing? Did you get an error? Do you have a code example you could add? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the Facebook PHP-SDK

Comment: thnx... get session in php sdk solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used php sdk and below are the codes:

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(…);
 $session = $facebook->getSession();
 if ($session) {
 // proceed knowing you have a valid user session
 } else {
  // proceed knowing you require user login and/or authentication
 }
```